# Having problem using sed | Trying to replace a line

Tags: sed

Contents of gaurav.txt file

```
$generalNetPath = "/net";
$generalNetPath = "/glbusers4/glb/aimsys/apxwrk48";
```

I trying to replace `/glbusers4/glb/aimsys/apxwrk48` by `pwd` as follows

```
qaz=`pwd`
sed '/apxwrk/c\$generalNetPath = "$qaz";' gaurav.txt
```

I am getting the output as

```
$generalNetPath = "/net";
$generalNetPath = "$qaz";
```

I was expecting `$qaz` be replaced by my present working directory.As far as my knowledge this is happening because of `'` (single quotes) that I am using.I have tried using `\` before `"` but that didn't help.Is there any anyway can I do this.I mean can I use anything other than `'` so that I can have value of `$pwd` replaced by using any character other than `'` .I tried using `|` but didn't work.Please help me out with this.

Comment: Note that in POSIX shells, the current working directory is in the `$PWD` variable.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out myself.Here is the syntax.Thanks anyway.

```
sed "/apxwrk/c\$generalNetPath = \"$qaz\";" gaurav.txt
```

Comment: Yes or you could also use single quotes on the inside, which would work better in some circumstances (and worse only in the circumstance that your working directory name includes single quotes).